# How to clone AppCompat SeekBar material thumb drawable for a custom View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-seekbar

When I use AppCompat theme in Activity and have a SeekBar in layout, its thumb drawable is a regular material thumb drawable for Android 5.0+ (Lollipop) and a circle that becomes bigger when pressed in previous version of Android. In both cases it's colored with accent color as well.

I want to use same drawable in a custom View (which doesn't extend SeekBar) , but how do I achieve same result (coloring included)?

What I tried:

1) Getting drawable xml from AppCompat but it's black - likely need to apply a ColorFilter to paint it properly. And that obviously doesnt solve the problem for material (Lollipop+) version.

2)Copying xmls from Android sources from themes for those drawables, but they use some attributes that aren't publicly available (opticalInsetLeft for example)

Any help and directions greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your custom view a `SeekBar` as well? If so why not just extend `AppCompatSeekBar`?

Comment: @CoryCharlton no, it's not. Thanks, it's worth mentioning